# Syntax error near unexpected token « done »

Tags: linux, bash

error

```
m2tsac3.sh: ligne9: Syntax error near unexpected token « done »
m2tsac3.sh: ligne9: `           done'
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash 

 find . -name "*.m2ts" | while read line
           do
             name="$(basename "${line}" .m2ts)"
             echo "${name}"
             ffmpeg -i "${name}".m2ts  -map 0:1 -acodec ac3 "${name}".ac3 

           done
```

hello i have an syntax error

the script is to extract audio from m2ts file to AC3 for all the m2ts file from folder

thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the second pipeline `bash` expects following the `&&`?

Comment: I remove && / was wrong
and it works but it does not loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg` reads from standard input, consuming the rest of the input from `find`. Redirect its standard input from `/dev/null`:

```
find . -name "*.m2ts" | while read line
       do
         name="$(basename "${line}" .m2ts)"
         echo "${name}"
         ffmpeg -i "${name}".m2ts  -map 0:1 -acodec ac3 "${name}".ac3 < /dev/null

       done
```